# Getting all tables inside a database using Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, laravel-4

### What do I want to achieve?

Get all table names inside a database and echo them using `@foreach @endforeach`.
My database name is demoproject and it has some tables inside it like users, list1, list2, list3 and I need to echo all the tables.

When using var dump I get bool(true) or when echoing I get 1 with this code `DB::statement('show tables from demoproject');`

### Why do I want to do this?

I'm making an admin panel, where I can edit tables and their rows. That's why I need to use `@foreach` to link them to another page.

I only need to know how I can echo all tables inside that database to continue with this project.

I'm using Laravel 4.

Comment: Why not just include PHPMyAdmin in your application?

Comment: Because I need to encrypt some values using php. And I don't want all admins to edit some rows.

Plus I'll be adding descriptions on how to edit/insert values etc..

Comment: Could you please stop questioning my method of doing this?

Comment: Why not? comments intended for clarification. If you don't feel like  answering them - just don't answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema='database_name'
```

you can also do this to test or whatnot:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
//run queries the normal pdo way
```

For PGSQL;

```
    if (config('database.default') == 'pgsql') {
        $database_name = 'laravel';
        $tables = DB::select("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'");

        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $tablename = $table->table_name;
            if ($tablename == 'model_has_permissions' || $tablename == 'password_resets'|| $tablename == 'model_has_roles' 
                || $tablename == 'model_has_permissions'|| $tablename == 'role_has_permissions') {
                continue;
            }
                DB::select("
                SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('$table->table_name' , 'id'), coalesce(max(id)+1, 1), false)
                FROM ".$tablename.";
            ");
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 34):

A little bit late, however, you can run `$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');` to get all tables.

Comment: My only question here is that you wouldn't be able to iterate through this list without already knowing the name of the database I think. It comes back like this:

    {"Tables_in_notes":"gdocs"},{"Tables_in_notes":"migrations"}

So to get a list, you'd have to know the project is called "notes" right?

Comment: @TommyNicholas, it's not a project name, but database name which you can usually get by `env('DB_DATABASE')`

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in Laravel 5.2 with Microsoft SQL 2012

```
$tables = DB::connection('<connection_name')
               ->table('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES')
               ->select('*')
               ->get();
dd($tables);
```